# CSS content area of our site is scrolling when it should not

Tags: html, css, header, footer

Ok, so the issue is I have a header, footer and the content div and what I want is for the content div to auto fill the height of the browser between header and footer making the footer stay on the bottom of the page, or below the content length.

when you go to [incard.com.au](http://incard.com.au) you can see the issue on the index page as the content area is smaller then the browser window so we have added a height to the div to solve the footer floating issue.

I fixed it using jquery

```
$('#sitewidth').css({'height':(($(document).height())-320)+'px'});
        $('#contentbody').css({'height':(($(document).height())-320)+'px'});
```

Comment: Do you want the footer to be fixed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the solution by using Javascript, it seems that to get the height of the content to fit the whole screen correctly I had to do a math thing where I took the height of the footer and header away from the browser screen size and then that gave me the min-size of my content body. as it is different on each users screen size it had to be a javascript set function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'min-height: 700px' from #contentbody

Comment: yes but on our screen we see the orange border stop and not go all the way to the footer

Comment: I did what you said, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

So what is supposed to happen when the browser window is smaller than the height of the div?

You can set the height of the central div at 100 percent.  For example, make the content div 100%, make the top and bottom fixed heights.  That's kind of a hack but it works sometimes I think -- the 100% won't compress the fixed height top and bottom -- it "tries" to be 100%.

What I'm unclear about is what's supposed to happen as you make the browser window smaller.  Is the header and footer supposed to stay glued to the top and bottom of your browser, while the content area gets smaller and smaller?

Comment: if the window is smaller then the content then users will have to scroll. but what if a users screen size is BIGGER then the content then as you can now see the orange border stops.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see is that the orange borders on each side of your content area stop half-way down the page when the content doesn't reach the footer.

The most common way to fix this issue it to make those orange borders a background image and have it repeat-y inside of `.sitewidth`

Comment: yes that would be a way, but I really not wanting to do that as I thnk thats the easy way out? What I need is it to relize that the content is smaller the then browser and make the height fit.

Comment: The way I have described is the only good way with pure CSS that is well supported in today's browsers. The `CSS flexible box model module` would work, but it's not supported in IE. You could also do a combination of `overflow:hidden` with `margin-bottom:-99999em; padding-bottom:99999em;`, but that's not always reliable and MUCH more hackish than just using a background image.